# Как отсортировать колонки от больше всего коррелирующих с первой колонкой до менее всего корреллирующих?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, машинное-обучение, статистика, анализ-данных

Как в DataFrame с колонками A, B, C, D (например) отсортировать колонки B, C, D от больше всего коррелирующих с A до менее всего корреллирующих?

Спрашиваю затем, чтобы научиться автоматизировать поиск самых подходящих для машинного обучения признаков X для поиска y. Следовательно, если, допустим, есть 100 признаков для X, а мне нужно взять 5-ть, которые более всего коррелируют с y, то не охота это делать руками (глазами), так как можно ошибиться. Проще же переложить это на программу.

Answer (score 3):

Судя по вопросу, вы хотите выбрать наиболее важные/сильные признаки из набора `X`, которые позволят предсказать значения в столбце `y`. Корреляцию обычно расчитывают для противоположных целей - сильно коррелирующие признаки чаще всего ухудшают качество модели, поэтому от них стараются избавиться. В вашем случае вам надо выбрать наиболее важные признаки, т.е. те котороые максимально влияют на качество работы модели. Для этого существует несколько подходов:

1. `Feature Importance` - ранжирование признаков по степени влияния на качество работы модели. Чаще всего для этого используют алгоритмы "решающих деревьев" или их ансамбли.
2. `Feature Selection` - выбор наиболее важных признаков.
3. `Dimensionality Reduction` - уменьшения размерности пространства признаков. Грубо говоря, мы проецируем вектора признаков в пространство с меньшей размерностью так, чтобы  потерять минимум полезной информации. Это как создавать порошковый сок из фруктов - мы пытаемся оставить все самое ценное (экстракт) и избавиться от лишнего.

PS корреляция не всегда способна уловить сложные зависимости и шаблоны. Например один из самых популярных алгоритмов расчёта коэффициента корреляции по Пирсону - способен найти только линейные зависимости между парой столбцов / признаков.

Comment: Это да. Но вообще хотелось бы как раз убрать коррелирующие колонки (признаки)

Comment: @ViktorAndriichuk, тогда непонятна фраза "мне нужно взять 5-ть, которые более всего коррелируют с `y`" - вам нужно избавляться от тех признаков, которые коррелируют между собой, а не с `y`

Comment: взять, чтобы избавиться (удалить). тут же главное как найти коррелирующие )

Comment: @ViktorAndriichuk, логическая ошибка у вас в части `коррелируют с `y`` - не там ищете. Искать нужно корреляции в пространстве признаков. Т.е. в `X`.

Comment: ок. спасибо за подсказку

Comment: Да, лучше убирать коррелирующие между собой, а не с таргетом. По корреляции с таргетом обычно наоборот делают - удаляют фичи, которые совсем слабо коррелируют с таргетом, если фич слишком уж много и модели тормозят из-за этого.

Answer (score 2):

Полностью если, то как-то так:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(1000,100))
df_corr = df.loc[:,df.columns[np.argsort(abs(df.corr()[0]))][-6:]]
```

Это если оставить и колонку 0, с которой смотрится корреляция.
Могу и в 'ABCD...' колонки переписать, но думаю принцип понятен.

Comment: Класс. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Pandas, метод df.corr()

Результат - матрица попарной корреляции  между всеми столбцами DataFrame.

Необязательный параметр method  позволяет выбрать алгоритм корреляции (Присона, Спирмана, Кендалла).

Вопрос - всегда-ли самые коррелированные столбцы есть "лучшими" при машинном обучении - здесь оставим за скобками (по правилам данного формуа это другой вопрос).

Comment: Ну, зря за скобками. Помнится, для некоторых методов машинного обучения сильно коррелированные между собой столбцы - это боль. Так что подчеркнуть стоит.

Comment: @CrazyElf  -  так и я о том. Но не следует мешать вопрос "как технически" с вопросом "зачем" и как  "как надо (семантически)"